# Installing multiple configuration profiles with CALDAV payloads on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, caldav

I would like to provide two links on the `iOS` app that I am working on now for downloading two configuration profiles using safari. Both are configured to install `CALDAV` payloads and nothing else. The profiles were configured with different name, identifier, description under general and with different account description, Account Host name under `CalDAV` payload. Left the other fields unattended. Exported the profiles and hosted on an internal server. Created two `html` files to provide the download links from safari. But I am not able to install both the profiles simultaneously. One profile will get installed and the details will appear on the settings page of `iPhone`, and when I try to install the other, it always shows this alert `"Profile Installation Failed"` `"Profile Failed to Install"`.

Am I missing something here, or is it because that Apple may only allow multiple `CalDAV` payloads on the same configuration profile (which works properly). Are there any limitations on the number of configuration profiles that could be installed on a device. But I also observed that one of the configuration profile that I created will get installed alongside that of `TestFlight`. So I feel multiple configuration profiles on the same device should work somehow, but I haven't got any success on it yet.

> **Please note** that I created the configuration profiles using the `'iPhone Configuration Utility'` app in `MAC`, and none of the profiles were signed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this for over two days now, finally I found a workaround. Though I doubt if it is a solution, but still it worked for me. So far I have been trying to configure the profile using the iPhone Configuration Utility on my MAC only. On checking the mobile config files, I found that the value corresponding to the key "PayloadUUID" is the same for all the profiles that I created using my MAC machine. Then I tried creating one profile from my MAC and the other from that of my colleague's, and it worked perfectly.

So we could possibly fix the above mentioned issue by configuring the profiles from different machines or by simply editing the profiles such that the "PayloadUUID" are different.

If anybody else finds a better solution, please do update.